# How to detect and prevent zombies?

Tags: c, background-process, zombie-process

preventing zombies : i have a child process running in the background (within another process group using setpgid()) , how can i prevent it from becoming a zombie??
my code :

```
`   process_arglist(arglist[] , count){
    //background process
    if(strcmp(arglist[count-1],"&")==0){
        int pid = fork();
        if(pid<0){ perror("fork error"); exit(1); }
        if(pid==0){
            arglist[count-1]=NULL;
            setpgid(0,0);
            if(execvp(*arglist , arglist)<0){
                perror("execution error");
                exit(1);
            }
        }else{
            //signal handling , zombies and stuff
            return 1;
        }
    }}`
```

any help would be appreciated '
thanx in advance

Comment: You prevent it becoming a zombie by ensuring its parent process reaps it once it completes.

Comment: regarding: `if(execvp(*arglist , arglist)<0){`   when any `exec...()` function returns, it is an error, so no need  for the `if()` wrapper.